# How to fill up the interior of the ellipses with red blue and green colors?

Tags: plotting, regions

```
ContourPlot[
  {x^2 + 9 y^2 + 1.5 x y == 19,
   x^2 + 4 y^2 + x y == 35,
   x^2 + 16 y^2 + x y == 26},
  {x, -7, 7}, {y, -4, 4}, 
  ContourStyle -> {Red, Blue, Green}
]
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is an idea using `RegionPlot`:

```
Show@MapThread[
  RegionPlot[#1, {x, -7, 7}, {y, -4, 4},
    PlotStyle -> Directive[#2, Opacity[0.1]],
    BoundaryStyle -> #2
  ]&,
  {
    {x^2 + 9 y^2 + 3/2 x y <= 19, x^2 + 4 y^2 + x y <= 35, x^2 + 16 y^2 + x y <= 26}, 
    {Red, Darker@Green, Blue}
  }
]
```

[image: plot]

As a note, at first I thought I could just use a single call to `RegionPlot` with the three equations and the appropriate `PlotStyle -> {Red, Green, Blue}, BoundaryStyle -> {Red, Green, Blue}`, but it seems that BoundaryStyle does not support multiple boundary specifications (the last one specified is the only one used). Perhaps I am misunderstanding there.

Comment: Thank you so much

Comment: The problem is solved. Could you please edit or remove the plot(for copyright issues)? It would be highly appreciated if you do so. Please.

Comment: @Sahabub 1) If you find that one of the answers provided here has solved your problem, you can indicate that by accepting upvoting it and accepting it (click gray checkmark by the answer). 2) What copyright issues are you trying to solve specifically? The content of this answer is available under the Creative Commons license [CC BY-SA 4.0](https://creativecommons.org/licenses/by-sa/4.0/).

Answer (score 0):

```
Show @ MapThread[ContourPlot[#, {x, -7, 7}, {y, -4, 4}, Contours -> {#2}, 
    ContourStyle -> Darker@#3, ContourShading -> {Opacity[.4, #3], None}] &,
   {{x^2 + 4 y^2 + x y, x^2 + 16 y^2 + x y, x^2 + 9 y^2 + 1.5 x y},
    {35, 26, 19}, 
    {Blue, Green, Red}}]
```

[image]

Alternatively, you can use `RegionPlot`:

```
Show @ MapThread[RegionPlot[#, {x, -7, 7}, {y, -4, 4}, PlotStyle -> Opacity[.5, #2], 
    BoundaryStyle -> Darker@#2] &, 
  {{x^2 + 4 y^2 + x y <= 35,  x^2 + 16 y^2 + x y <= 26, x^2 + 9 y^2 + 1.5 x y <= 19}, 
  { Blue, Green, Red}}]
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you so much.

Comment: The problem is solved. Could you please edit or remove the plot(for copyright issues)? It would be highly appreciated if you do so. Please.

Comment: @SahabubJahedi You seem to have a strange conception of how this site works.  What exactly is your concern?  Your Question and the Answers you received do not contain private or confidential data.

Comment: Please try to understand. Actually, I am trying to make some notes. This plot may be there with the same legend name. So. If I try to upload in some specific online portal they may not allow me to upload it. I will be highly obliged if you edit it or remove it. Please, it's a request